# Where can I find a list of itemize bullet shapes in LaTex Beamer?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I've read about changing the shape of the itemize bullet in the `Beamer` class documentation and also on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2822345/735756) which shows how to change the bullet shape to a checkmark (`\checkmark`).

Where can I find the complete list of the bullet shapes available for the Beamer class?

Comment: Do you change it for one itemize or the whole document? Since you can use nearly every symbol here is a list showing a lot of them: http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: I would like to change it for the whole document.. Thanks for the list! :)

Comment: Take a look at `pifont` package which includes the environment `\begin{dinglist}{number}` where `number` can be any of the ones listed [here](http://willbenton.com/wb-images/pifont.pdf)

Comment: @Rico seems the link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @seteropere : I think it might be here now: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You'll find those predefined templates in [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). 
Here are those which are listed in the guide (Chap. 12  Structuring a Presentation: The Local Structure p. 111)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\mf{
\begin{itemize}
\item Item
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\mf
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\mf
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\mf
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\mf
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
\mf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Furthermore you can define your very own items:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\mf{
\begin{itemize}
\item Item
\end{itemize}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\tikz\node[cross out, draw] {good};}
\mf
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{$\int$}
\mf
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you can't change the bullet while **inside** an itemize environment.

Comment: @Bach Yes, you can! At least with Texlive 2016 and Xelatex. Which is important for changing the symbols on nested itemize environments. However, I would prefer if they could be set individually for each nesting level.