# Change itemize symbol in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I am using beamer and gottingen style. I have nested itemize environments. For the last one, so the third level, I want to have not these bullet signs, but just circles. Currently I have:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\pretocmd{\appendix}{\let\appendixorig\relax}{}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\Large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\large}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting{mygreencode}[1]{%
  boxsep=1pt,
  boxrule=2pt,
  arc=3mm, 
  auto outer arc,
  colframe=green!40!
  black,colback=green!5,
  listing options={language=C},
  listing only,
  #1
}


\newenvironment{specialframe}
{
    \begingroup
    \advance\textwidth2cm % see beamerthemeGoettingen.sty for the number
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
    \begin{frame}[plain]
}
{
    \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}


\makeatletter
\usepackage{xpatch}
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{sep=0.3cm}{sep=0.6cm}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\frame{
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test


\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}




\end{document}
```

I now tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822345/how-do-you-change-the-image-of-a-bullet-point-in-latex-beamer) here. With \checkmark it does work:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item[\checkmark] Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

[image: e]

However, as I dont want \checkmarks, but a dot, I tried according to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93874/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-itemize-bullet-shapes-in-latex-beamer) to use circle:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item[\circle] Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

But this leads to an error. I also tried to use renewcommand according to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13463/specifying-bullet-type-when-using-itemize):

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\circ$}
```

But no matter where I put it, I get an error that the control sequence is undefined.

When I try `\item[$\circ$]` I get a circle, but it is not colored:

[image: E2]

I want to have this one here from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93874/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-itemize-bullet-shapes-in-latex-beamer):

[image: e4]

How can I change the sign to a fully colored circle/dot for the last nested itemize environment?

Comment: `\item[\textbullet] Test` should work

Comment: Yes! It did. You can post it as an answer. Where can I find a list of possible entries? And why is all the \renewcommand{\labelitemi} not working?

Comment: I have added an answer with an even more general/global approach and a list of predefined options.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}` is nor working in combination with `beamer` since `beamer` has its own way of handling `itemize` (and `enumerate`) lists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to locally change a single symbol of an `itemize` in beamer to a colored circle, you could use `\item[\textbullet] ...`.

For a global change of all itemize symbols fo a certain level, you can use

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize <level>}[<predefined symbol>]{<custom symbol>}
```

With `<level>`:

`item` --> first level

`subitem` --> second level

`subsubitem`--> third level

and   with one of the following predefined options: `triangle`, `circle` `square` or `ball` or  with a different symbol of your choice.

---

To summarize: To globally change all itemize symbols of all third level itemize environments, add `\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[circle]` to your preamble.

Comment: Thanks and I will accept. But "or with a different symbol of your choice" You gave triangle, circle, square and ball. How can I use a symbol of my own choice? Furthermore: Is there  a list with further predefined options, so not only triangle circle square and ball, or are there just these 4 standard symbols?

Comment: You can use one of the predefined options (as shown in my answer) or a different symbol of your choice as follows: `\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\checkmark}` with `\checkmark` being the "different symbol of choice"  in this example. `\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{+}` would give you a `+` as itemize symbol. Predefined options are used in a set of `[]`, the code for custom symbols goes in a set of `{}`. I hope that made it clearer. You can find an overview/description on page 114 of the `beamer` user manual.

Comment: Ok thanks, but are there any other than triangle, circle square or ball? So I can use \item[\textbullet]  \item[\circle]  \item[\square]  \item[\ball] or any other? When I try to use \item[\ball]  \item[\circle]  \item[\square] or \item[\triangle] these all are not working, only \item[\textbullet] works. Don't know why. So my question in the comment was, if there are other possibilities then \item[\textbullet] (I thought square or ball and so like you mentioned should work the same way but they do not work), so a list of entries I can use.

Comment: Do you want to change all itemize symbols of one level or just a single symbol?

Comment: To globally change the symbol, use the `\setbeamertemplate` method. If you want to locally change the symbol to one of the predefined symbols, take a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292903/134144

Comment: Just single symbols. \item[\textbullet] is working, but not the others. I tried for example \item[\ball].

Comment: As already stated before: You can follow the example from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292903/134144. Add `\newenvironment{ballenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]}}{}` to your preamble and use `\item<ball@1-> A square item` in your document if you want to change a single itemize symbol to match the predefined ball style.

Comment: can we also change the number colors in the itemize symbols?

Comment: In-between "global" and "local", you can change all items of a specific itemize as follows: after `\begin{itemize}` and before your first `\item`, you can put the `\setbeamertemplate` command. This will not affect other `itemize` instances.